# Using the result of a 'previous' column in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

T-SQL appears to allow us to use the value of a column in an expression in another column, going left-to-right. E.g:

```
declare @a int, @b int;
select @a = 2, @b = @a * 3;
select @a, @b;
```

yields {2, 6}.

I can't find any reference to this 'feature' in BOL etc. My question is, is this known, dependable behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually covered as a **warning** in [Variables (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Warning
>
> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions. **Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the assignments.**

(Emphasis mine)

SQL server does assign the values one variable at a time, so in this (simple) example, SQL Server has assigned the value of `@a` prior to evaluating (and assigning) the expression `@a * 3` to `@b`.

As the warning says though, don't expect the behaviour to always be the same. If you need to guarantee that assignment is in a strict order, do the assignments as separate statements:

```
DECLARE @a int,
        @b int;
SET @a = 2;
SET @b  = @a * 3;
SELECT @a, @b;
```

Edit: This behaviour does **not** exist when using expressions that are not assignments. For example the following statement will fail with the error *"Invalid column name 'a'."*:

```
SELECT 2 AS a,
       a * 3 AS b;
```

The behaviour you are describing only happens for assignment statements. You cannot reference a column by it's alias in the same `SELECT` it was defined.

Comment: "don't expect the behaviour to always be the same" - this is exactly the information I was looking for. Shame, looks like I've got some re-writes to do...

Comment: @RikBradley If this answers your question, then please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the docs that reads:

> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement,
>   SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the
>   expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are
>   references among the assignments.

It means there is no guarantee that it will evaluate the expression left-to-right. For this code:

```
declare @a int, @b int;
select @a = 2, @b = @a * 3;
select @a, @b;
```

The result could be `2, 6` (`@a = ...` evaluated first) or `2, NULL` (`@b = ...` evaluated first).